# What is that port with a chain-like logo on my laptop?

Tags: port

I found this port on my new laptop (a LG Gram). It is small, about the size of a mini-USB, and has a logo that looks like a chain. I don't have the documentation with me right now.

A [Google Image Reverse Search](https://www.google.co.kr/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZisWf5AyRIOaeqzPNUbyG9vT3_1WLVFVO7tIoXItfD4Jf4V5OnPvvHjD2sWVxzcuqGYGoOWI2COxoGqfSGXcJ_1ZXQaqPeGe8DoGHFunKmez7Ow40CjJTGsjAjbimZ8o4cMw70zBFDZByb4h-0a9OZPppU5wOv73mAxKC-Q7TeyhdWUZ_11VokRuZOvHrsmtwD_1TGtSRHjgtZhReIa0BZCJefjyJC6Ifn6tzmTnoQC2QjB1AitoWk5Qo5J3lbyeE0ZBHpDvlzd4oAJOUY3HjluRrpuDwuqmBrSzvR85Y89oKDgBu6JdIcl7Gd49XOiXnkMdpIh5OrRZwcLI6PrSeJlrMA7zADHIUp9mL6PdNpD7TUQhPJNjJ_1-mrm6iGoM2GQ--Kx_1iMxOazKIPHg4ECi7vpQtU9yVqcuqUDdjruqzHZboFkXV_1VQdGJB1TSfKAL1fckbdepyenMPm497BclQ2VJXm6_1cOJpSRbVW9J2PVuRywcY8wVSOuV_1BFAqO75j73Mtr9by-H7L3c7iqremgf5_1iIzPvHczebMMnC0nUx3f3Se50pe6XfFta67tsTTeFigX-N5pdKid_1HF89PcXuYKD0dESwN8ZqmMVPU0JL3-2wOMwrem884mdem6l1nsSdj-iRNBC-puyGqck9olzpDMwXtlDA0up6NRlsoOXsrzKgr8MplcRvZjm5l8ECUhOPajTlYG-Mq82EkWzd5cf1jsvfBfhCYd6gRYPOaz3Fh3-bVzSgryP9o5M6KPhKMOUgGglGXvJ4DJc2cv8l_1bhTWZ-LNzkYs4nU-IbUBYYCz72gSLvDxJbkXUMy6yb5VtwiF0P-ptbLUvltRg4zwimC_13xkCk-Ni5v4ch3osI5ILTpLfhc0vI9CDNia77VtDatSOsg1qIkJIhufo1xMOMCfmf2BiEsarzx3YpKw9wGJuy0Oe-wOtv8ufX-2T4KW36MS5RuDvN95qf8UGIx9VEHcaETh1Kmx_1oqEuIhdc7Skw16QN7H_1MESToB0-WB5GpSxDkBwNA69xRc_1v6JYohJGEZEAbQPILBokBEFcydRSjD-3ZO-Rbmr2cIjO0KCkXC4yyStbNesQm0H4op247Z_1iwSQZNBkBUpWsa_1ThxYsXcdRA7NNSUGmV1hVCC_12BlmekaARa_1ADjYJODS3Up9KTiSKUpMHeEIInAW-Y9QX1l3G78WLw_1HReegxsOSEVVPLAm3xNz_139g2k2QdY-J1fatY3Be8cs2QASCYRmlVy5du4EAJHOWcTpPlhHi93_1nD7Fc48UB_1kq4szXIt6N5n4qNL0S4oGK9kAPw3PFlKi-9N627SBI1YI4FSHXM6VdBFQQsJGITjJbruW1_1uge3hLRB1qkUqcggyIw9w&hl=fr-KR) returns nothing except "Gadget". I couldn't find anything with a normal Google search.

I also tried to look at several questions here but for some unknown reason, the pictures in the similar questions don't load (and I have no problem to see picture on SciFi.SE for example). They seem not to match my question.

[image: port]

Comment: This question is now marked duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate question.

Comment: @Twisty This one's actually 4th in the duplicate chain... the first duplicate has the same image, but the next two are *not really duplicates*, they've got different or no symbols

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is for a lock to physically secure your PC, or a lot of other electronic gadgets, from theft.

It is an accepted standard known as [**Kensington lock**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kensington_Security_Slot). For which you can buy all kind of locks, like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005J7Y99W):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think its the security cable securing point,  that is where you plug in the lock on the physical security cable- I cant find a reference/photo but shape of the hole looks like the one on my Dell laptop